# compare a python list with strings which are extracted from html using BeautifulSoup python3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am working on a project in python using BeautifulSoup in which i am trying to extract data from html. i have already extracted some data but now i am facing some issues that is i have this list
category=['author', 'pinglun', 'renqi', 'step', 'gongyi', 'nandu', 'renshu', 'kouwei', 'zbshijian', 'prshijian']
and in my html document, there is a value associated to each of the element in the above list. i have tried this code but this is just retrieving value of one element i.e "author". i want to extract values of all the elements in the above "category" list

```
for script in scripts:
if "_BFD.BFD_INFO" in script.text:
    text=script.text
    m_text=text.split('=')
    m_text = text.split('=')
    m_text = m_text[2].split(":")
    m_text = m_text[1].split(',')
    encoded = m_text[0].encode('utf-8')
    print(encoded.decode('utf-8'))
category=['author', 'pinglun', 'renqi', 'step', 'gongyi', 'nandu', 
'renshu', 'kouwei', 'zbshijian', 'prshijian']
for script in scripts:
text=script.text
m_text=text.split(',')
for n in m_text:
    if 'author'  in n:
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `for`-loop to check for each category in the text-segment:

```
for script in scripts:
    if "_BFD.BFD_INFO" in script.text:
        text=script.text
        m_text=text.split('=')
        m_text = text.split('=')
        m_text = m_text[2].split(":")
        m_text = m_text[1].split(',')
        encoded = m_text[0].encode('utf-8')
        print(encoded.decode('utf-8'))
    category=['author', 'pinglun', 'renqi', 'step', 'gongyi', 'nandu', 
    'renshu', 'kouwei', 'zbshijian', 'prshijian']
    for script in scripts:
        text=script.text
        m_text=text.split(',')
        for n in m_text:
            for c in category:
                if c in n:
                   print(n)
```